# Banner Slider in Swiper Slider inside Tab Menu Tab Panel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

I already tried to create a Slider with a Imageslider in it and all this in a TabMenu Container. But I got problems with the font and I don't find the problem.

TabMenu -> Swiper (Slider) -> Unslider (Slider).

Sometimes i refresh or reload the site there is the problem like in the image shown below. I dont know how and why the problem appears.

jsfiddle.net/mqstw6zj/6/

[image]

Comment: where is your code ?

Comment: Added. Jsfiddle link, ten chars.